# Something wrong into where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sum, where-clause

I have below select:

```
select sum(col1) as sum1 
from table1
where col2 = 'A' and col3 in ('AA','BB')
```

Now when I did:

```
select sum(col1) as sum2 
from table1
where col2 <> 'A' and col3 not in ('AA','BB')
```

and try to add: **sum1+sum2**, I should got total sum of (col1). But some value is missing. Do you know why?

[image]

Comment: what does this mean "But some value is missing" .Can you elaboarate.. But some value is missing.provide some sample data and check how to ask  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you check for `NULL`?

Comment: These two where conditions are not the exact opposite of each other. The AND in the below query should be OR.

Comment: try to: where (col2='A' and col3 not in ('AA','BB') and col2 <> 'A' and col3 in ('AA')) ---but is wrong :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two queries are not completely complementary, You are missing `NULL` values to start. You are also missing `WHERE col2 = 'A' AND col3 NOT IN ('AA', 'BB')` and `WHERE col2 <> 'A' and col3 IN ('AA', 'BB')`.

Like I said you are also missing `NULL`, you can check like this: `WHERE col2 IS NULL OR col3 IS NULL`

**edit** Requested is the alternate query of the first one given:

```
select  sum(col1) as sum2 
from    table1
where   col2 <> 'A' 
     OR col3 not in ('AA','BB')
     OR col2 IS NULL
     OR col3 IS NULL
```

Comment: What do you intend to achieve?

Comment: I need to split the sum value....from first query I got ok sum, from the second query I want to remove rows from first query to get rest of sum

Answer (score 0):

Because there could be rows where col2 = 'A' and col3 not in ('AA','BB')
or 
col2 <> 'A' and col3 in ('AA','BB')